# How to modify this vbs to run bat with multiple params, for example, 3?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, vbscript, parameter-passing

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

The vbs above invisibly runs bat script provided in call

```
wscript.exe "vbsfilename.vbs" "batfilename.bat"
```

What if it is required to provide some params for .bat via

```
wscript.exe "vbsfilename.vbs" "batfilename.bat" "paramA" "paramB" "paramC"?
```

How should vbs be modified?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it there:

> CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & THERE """", 0, False

When you run a .bat file from the .Run command, the parameters are placed after the  path and are separated by spaces (you have to put quotes if you want to send a parameter containing a space). The best way to try the command is by opening a CMD.

Example(on CMD): batfilename.bat value1 value2 value3

I cannot help more without any precision about why you need to do this on two separated VBScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out:

```
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """ """
& WScript.Arguments(1) & """ """
& WScript.Arguments(2) & """ """
& WScript.Arguments(3) & """", 0, False
```